# Formula Written in Module Producing #VALUE

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

With assistance from outside sources I have this code that takes latitude and longitude and extracts zipcodes. Here is the code:

```
Public Function ReverseGeoCode(myInput1 As String, myInput2 As String) As String

'You will need to reference Microsoft XML, v6.0 object library

    Dim XMLDoc As New DOMDocument60
    Dim XMLNODE As IXMLDOMNode
    Dim I As Long
    Dim lat, lng, myAddress, myZipcode, reportZipcode As String
    Dim splitAddress, splitZipcode As Variant

    lat = myInput1
    lng = myInput2

    XMLDoc.Load "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" & lat & "," & lng & " &sensor=false"

    Do Until XMLDoc.readyState = 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    If Len(XMLDoc.Text) = 0 Then
        Call MsgBox("No Data!")
        Exit Function
    End If

    Set XMLNode = XMLDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address")

    For i= 0 To XMLNode.ChildNodes.Length - 1
        myAddress = XMLNode.ChildNodes(i).Text
    Next i

    splitAddress = Split(myAddress, ",")
    myZipcode = splitAddress(2)
    myZipcode = Trim(myZipcode)
    splitZipcode = Split(myZipcode, " ")
    reportZipcode = splitZipcode(1)
    reportZipcode = Trim(reportZipcode)

    ReverseGeoCode = reportZipcode

End Function
```

So the code works, and I know it might not be the cleanest. But the issue is when I call it in the Excel sheet using "=ReverseGeoCode(Cell1, Cell2)". Sometimes it works fine, other times it produces the return "#VALUE!" and I am not entirely sure why. I attached an image below to show you an example of the error. Does anyone have an idea of why this error is producing?[image: (Image of Error in Excel Sheet)]

Comment: Instead of an UDF which requires frequent recalculation. Can you not write a sub and have it output results to the sheet? Tie that to a button. More efficient and more reliable. And you can also then remove the duplicates.

Comment: Moment of vulnerability, I got a lot of help with this and essentially did what I was told. What is a UDF? And how is it different from a regular sub?

Comment: An UDF is a user defined function. A function you define and call from a cell. I would avoid where possible. Someone may argue with me but if you don't need them, don't use them, is my motto.  When correcting the typos for example in your sheet where it shows #Value I get a msgbox saying no data.

Comment: @QHarr sorry about that. That was a type I was getting earlier on and corrected in the code, but didn't correct in notepad where I saved the example from, and copied into here. I edited it to reflect that. Yes I am open to any and all other solutions. I just don't have the experience to execute something like this without help so I went with what I was given.

Comment: @QHarr I appreciate your help and input. I'm not sure what either an PI key nor a JSON response/JSONConverter is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General observations:**

So to pick up on what I wrote in the comments, here is an outline.

You don't want to use an User Defined Function. This will keep on making repeated calls. You definitely risk hitting a call limit to the API without an API key, and possibly with; it is inefficient and it is not necessary. Instead, write a sub which you call once and which loops all the required cells in the sheet and issues the API calls and returns the zip codes. An API key is a method of authentication used with many API calls. You shouldn't share it by the way.

These repeated calls, possibly hitting a limit and the fact that UDFs are frequently calculated maybe the source of your woes.

With efficiency in mind, first remove duplicates from the sheet to avoid calls that are not required. Switch of Screen-Updating and anything else e.g. CalculationMode to manual whilst performing.

From what I have read you require an API key once you have hit a daily limit. Not sure what the API limit is for free version or without API key.

---

### **Outline code (XML request with some psuedo code):**

```
  Option Explicit
    Public Sub ListZipCodes()
        Dim lat As Double, longitude As Double
        Const APIKEY As String = "yourAPIkey"
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False           '<==Speed up code when actually working with sheet
        'Code to remove duplicates
        'Code to loop sheet and call function on each input set of values

        'Example call. These would be picked up from cells
        lat = 40.714224
        longitude = -73.961452

        Debug.Print GetZipCode(lat, longitude, APIKEY)

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub

    Public Function GetZipCode(ByVal lat As Double, ByVal longitude As Double, ByVal APIKEY As String) As String
        Dim sResponse As String
        With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            Dim URL As String
            URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" & lat & "," & longitude & "&key=" & APIKEY
            .Open "GET", URL, False
            .send
            If .Status <> 200 Then 
                GetZipCode = "API call failed"
                Exit Function
            End If
            Dim XMLDoc As New DOMDocument60, XMLNODE As IXMLDOMNode

            XMLDoc.Load .responseBody
            If Len(XMLDoc.Text) = 0 Then GetZipCode = "No data"

            Set XMLNODE = XMLDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address")
            GetZipCode = Split(Trim$(Split(XMLNODE.Text, Chr$(44))(2)), Chr$(32))(1)
        End With
    End Function
```

---

### **Requesting JSON rather than XML response:**

The reason calling as JSON was falling over was that the response needed to be decoded. Here is the function re-written to handle a JSON response.

This requires the download of [JSONConverter](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas), which you then import and add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime via VBE > Tools > References.

The example below was run with

```
latitude: 42.9865913391113, 
longitude: -100.137954711914
```

**VBA:**

```
Public Function GetZipCode(ByVal lat As Double, ByVal longitude As Double, ByVal APIKEY As String) As String
    Dim sResponse As String, json As Object
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        Dim URL As String, formattedAddress As String
        URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" & lat & "," & longitude & "&key=" & APIKEY
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        If .Status <> 200 Then 
            GetZipCode = "API call failed"
            Exit Function
        End If
        Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode))

        formattedAddress = json("results").item(1)("formatted_address")
        GetZipCode = Split(Trim$(Split(formattedAddress, Chr$(44))(2)), Chr$(32))(1)
    End With
End Function
```

With a JSON request the initial object you get back is a dictionary, as denoted by the opening `"{"` in the decoded response:

[image: JSON Object]

i.e. `Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode))` returns a dictionary object

The data of interest, in the dictionary, has the key `"results"`, as you may observe from the above.

This can be accessed with `json("results")`, which returns a collection of dictionaries. This being denoted by the following `"["`, for collection, and subsequently by the start of the first dictionary within the collection, indicated again by `"{"`.

[image: Collection of dictionaries]

I can grab the first dictionary in the collection by index with:

```
json("results").item(1)
```

An inspection of the keys in this dictionary shows that one of the keys is what we are after i.e.`"formatted_address"`.

[image: formatted_address key]

It's associated value is a primitive datatype; in this case a string. This means we can directly access it using the key (a further object is not returned).

```
formattedAddress = json("results").item(1)("formatted_address")
```

Now that we have the address string, we can parse it as we did before:

```
GetZipCode = Split(Trim$(Split(formattedAddress, Chr$(44))(2)), Chr$(32))(1)
```

---

**End note:**

You can use [*Postman*](https://www.getpostman.com/), amongst other tools, to test API calls, and in this case inspect the JSON response. Indeed, to see what kind of response you are getting full stop.

---

**Help:**

It is very quick and easy to set up a project, generate an API key and get started. Maybe 10 minutes to read through and perform.

1. [Instructions on setting up a project and getting an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key)
2. [Enabling the API](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158841)
3. [Understanding how to make API calls to the Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding)

Comment: Thank you for all your help, this looks really good and I am excited to try it out and see if we can get it rocking and rolling.

Comment: I can help along the way and potentially improve the above. This should help.

Comment: When running the code, I receive an "Argument Not Optional" compile error with the `GetZipCode(lat, longitude)` highlighted

Comment: I forgot to update the version I posted with the API key parameter in the function call. Done now.

Comment: It runs now, however I get a "Object variable or With block variable not set" error on the final statement of the function

Comment: on this line?  Set XMLNODE = XMLDoc.SelectSingleNode("/GeocodeResponse/result/formatted_address")  ?

Comment: No actually the one below it. Where you actually assign the value to GetZipCode

Comment: There is nothing being set here. It is not an object but a string that is being worked with. XMLNODE.Text.  Can you insert a line before and put Debug.print XMLNODE.Text ? I know it works. Have you changed anything? Can you give me the co-ordinates you are using? I am about to have dinner so will look after.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174960/discussion-between-qharr-and-matt-gaydon).